# Xamarin Missing Java and Android References / Namespace

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, namespaces, xamarin.android

Trying to build my first xamarin project using Visual Studio 2015.

Although the initial setup was a bit of pain I thought I finally had it until I started following the [Implementing Text-to-Speech](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/text-to-speech/) tutorial for xamarin.

I was following the one for android and none of the using reference added in work. I get many namespace errors.

I'm not sure what it needs or where to get them/add them.

Here are the errors I have.
http://hastebin.com/icironaqiq.tex

Comment: post the error here.

Comment: Compiled here http://hastebin.com/icironaqiq.tex

Comment: What are your min and max targets?

Comment: When I right click and check properties for my Droid Project it states.
 
Compile Using Android Platform: Latest Platform (Android 6.0 ),
Min Target: Android 4.0.3 (API Level 15),
Target Android Version: Use Compile Using SDK version.